# Adding animation to this jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

Have a fairly simple show/hide script for a set of data filters from a button. I've been looking at solutions on how to animate the transition but can't seem to see how this script differs from what's described on the jQuery site.

I read somewhere else that CSS3 animations might be easier or better but that also remains a mystery to me.

Is there an easy modification to this script:

```
$('.toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
});
```

Comment: What kind of animation are you wanting?  fade/slide down/slide right?

Comment: You have error in your code, comma after `'hidden show'`.

Comment: Oops on the error, left over from messing around, thanks.

Just a slide down animation. Very curious to see how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the classes, you can use the built-in toggleX methods (eg [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)).

If you want to do something more fancy such as animating colours, you'll need to look at the `animate` method and possibly including jquery-ui, which is where css3 transitions may be easier / less overhead unless you're already including jquery-ui.

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#target").toggle(500);
});

$("#slide").click(function() {
    $("#target").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Basic fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2j03v6d/

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple but I was just not finding the right page to understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what animation you're looking for but here I've used `slideToggle()` (http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) using some of the code you've provided: https://jsfiddle.net/8gavvmnL/1/

**HTML:**

```
<a class="toggle" href="#pop">Click Me</a>
<div id="pop">
  I'm hidden until the button is clicked!
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#pop").hide();
$('.toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Change `slideDown()` to `slideToggle()` for a better match with the requirement / OPs code

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.target').on( 'click', function () {
  var $stuff = $(this).find('.stuff');
  
  if ( $stuff.is(':visible') ) {
    $stuff.slideUp('slow');
  } else {
    $stuff.slideDown('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
.target .stuff {
  display: none;
  
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="target">
    Show/Hide
    <div class="stuff"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation / commentary with your answer, not just code.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for providing the CSS version of it. Wish there were multiple right answer checks for this.